# Asynchronous writes to Realm

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

The app is getting data from the server in many async API calls. When data is received it's processed an stored into Realm. Obviously, when writes happen to be at the same time `beginWriteTransaction` crashes the app since  Realm is already in a write transaction.

What's the best approach here? Put all writes into a serial dispatch queue?

Comment: don't call `beginWriteTransaction()` without a `commit()`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I call `commitWriteTransaction` in the end of each block that writes data to Realm.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I just read your article on Realm and I see I was using the dumb way of `beginWriteTransaction` and `commitWriteTransaction`. But still even with `transactionWithBlock` I would need some async approach to avoid crashes due to overlapping transactions, right?

Answer (score 1):

try to update realm in transactionWithBlock method instead.

```
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];

[realm transactionWithBlock:^{
    [realm addObject:mydog];
}];
```